# Why is my CELSIUS to RANKINE conversion failing when prompting user for a value for CELSIUS?

Tags: c, function, debugging, type-conversion

> Perform the following conversions to convert from CELSIUS to RANKINE:
>     degrees Fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0) * degrees Celsius + 32
>     degrees Rankine = degrees Fahrenheit + 459.67"

This program converts degrees [Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius) to degrees [Rankine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale). Prompt the user for a temperature in Celsius.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
double f,c,r;

    printf("Enter the temperature in degrees Celsius:" );
    scanf("%d", &c);

    f = (9.0/5.0) * c +32;
    r = f + 459.67;

    printf("After your conversion, your temperature in Rankin is: ", r);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: degrees Fahrenheit = (9.0/5.0) * degrees celsius + 32

Comment: degrees rankin = degrees fahrenheit + 459.67

Comment: Check the format specifiers! DO NOT YELL AT US! Add required information to your question, not as a comment! `return` is not a function.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &c);` --> `scanf("%lf", &c);`...`Rankin is: %f\n", r);`

Comment: what is wrong with my format?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12 And your `printf` has none at all.

Comment: i did not mean to yell, but highlight important specifics, sorry.

Comment: You can read the input as an int, but you would need to cast it to a double during computation. Also like @Olaf said your printf needs a format argument.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and use markup to highlight/format text.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY would i add the last reference for rankin after declaring the value at the end of my code?

Comment: @hiandbaii like an if statement?

Comment: The code does not compile cleanly.  1) in the printf(), 'too many arguments for format'  I.E. the format string does not contain a format specified for the 'r' parameter.  2) in the scanf(), 'format '%d' expects  argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'double *'   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix the warnings.  Please correct the code and re-post

Comment: @hiandbaii: He cannot, as the variable is `double` already, so he has to `scanf` a double, not an `int`. Conversion from `int` to `double` is implicit if one of the other operands is `double`.

Comment: thanks guys, helps tremendously

Comment: @Olaf, I did not state how to fix the problem, just repeating the warning messages from the compiler

Comment: @user3629249: I'm lacking context. Which comment of mine do you refer to? You comment ("The code does not compile cleanly...") looks fine to me.

Comment: the conversion from Celsius to Rankin is:  'ºR =
ºC * 1.8000
+ 491.67'  so there is no need to clutter the code with the intermediate step of converting to Fahrenheit.

Comment: @Olaf,  The comment that contains: 'He cannot, as the variable is double already'  Perhaps I made an error in assuming that your comment was directed toward my original comment.  If your refering to my suggestion that the code be corrected and re-posted, my understanding is selecting the code, then pressing <ctrl>-k would allow the posted code to be edited.

Comment: I'd prefer to have all in Kelvin first. And add Réaumur, Rømer, (good ol') Newton and Planck, of course. (btw. it's Rankine, not Rankin)

Comment: @user3629249: My comment was addressed to hiandbaii; I don't see a relation to your comment. But I do not agree with editing/re-posting the code, as that would change the question (it would actually make the question irrelevant - horray).

Comment: figured it out, #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
/* initialize variables for conversion */
double c ,r;
/*prompt user for a value via Celisus */
 printf("This program converts degrees Celsius to degrees Rankin.\n");
 printf("Enter the temperature in degrees Celsius>\n" );
 scanf("%lf", &c);
/* conversions that will execute to determine values from Celsius to Rankin */ 
 r = ((9.0/5.0) * c + 32) + 459.67;  
 
/* Print conversion results below */ 
 printf("%lf degrees Celsius = %lf degrees Rankin", c, r);
 
 
 return(0);
 

 
}

Comment: @user3453693: Did you read my note about your misspelling the name of Mr. Rankine?

Comment: @Olaf LSNED - I had same spelling error [Rankine scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is my CELSIUS to RANKINE conversion failing when prompting user for a value for CELSIUS?

Code is using the incorrect type of data per the format specifiers.  For type `double`, scan with `"%lf"` and to print use `"%f"`

1. [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237804/why-is-my-celsius-to-rankin-conversion-failing-when-prompting-user-for-a-value-f#comment52357929_32237804) comment to use the matching format specifiers in `sncaf()` and `printf()`:
2. Insure prompt is flushed.
3. Check `scanf()` return value.

.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double f,c,r;

  printf("Enter the temperature in degrees Celsius:" );
  fflush(stdout); 
  if (scanf("%lf", &c) != 1) {
    puts("Non-numeric input" );
    return -1;
  } 

  f = (9.0/5.0) * c +32;
  printf("After your conversion, your temperature in Fahrenheit is: %.1f F", f);

  r = f + 459.67;
  printf("After your conversion, your temperature in Rankine is: %.1f R", r);
  return 0;
}
```